# jQuery bind element visibility with condition

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button in a table caption with the id="data", i would like to keep it hidden as long as the table rows are 0

How can i attach some conditional event to the button visible property or something like that?

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                    <caption style="caption-side:top;">
                        <button onclick="getRandomLocalizacoesAjax()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button id="data" onclick="insertRandomLocalizacoesAjax()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </button>
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Localização</th>
                            <th>Etiquetas</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function, e.g. `toggleDataButton()`, that you can invoke when you manipulate table rows. You can also invoke the function on page load to set the initial state.

You will also benefit from setting an id (e.g. `id="dataTable"`) on the table for effortless lookup.

```
const tableBody = $("#dataTable > tbody");

function toggleDataButton () {
  $("#data").toggle( tableBody.children().length !== 0 );
}
```

Here's a quick mock up of how you would want to invoke your function when changing table contents. Clicking the sync button will append rows to the table. Clicking the trash button will clear the table. Your button will toggle its visibility.

```js
const tableBody = $("#dataTable > tbody");

// button visibility
function toggleDataButton () {
  $("#data").toggle( tableBody.children().length !== 0 );
}

// simulate appending table contents
function getRandomLocalizacoesAjax () {
  let r = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
  tableBody.append(`<tr>
    <td>${r()}</td>
    <td>${r()}</td>
  </tr>`);
  toggleDataButton();
}

// simulate clearing of table
function clearTable () {
  tableBody.empty();
  toggleDataButton();
}

// execute on dom ready
$(document).ready(function () {
  toggleDataButton();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
  <caption style="caption-side:top;">
    <button onclick="getRandomLocalizacoesAjax()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></button>
    <button id="data" onclick="insertRandomLocalizacoesAjax()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
    <button id="clearData" onclick="clearTable()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Localização</th>
      <th>Etiquetas</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i had made a small solution in the meantime for this but not as detailed as this one. Pretty neat.

Comment: Also could you explain if it's more performant to give an id to table rather than just select it using it's element when i only have one table on this page? Because I usually just select by the element if it's a form or a single table on the current page

Comment: There are many explanations on performance here on this site. But in a nutshell, jQuery uses getElementById under the hood for id selectors, and querySelector for all others which is 97% slower regardless of how many elements you have on the page. [Further reading](https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/)

Comment: That's good to hear there is something i can improve on all my projects.